# categorise df based on date ranges, with multiple factor levels

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by

How might I categorize each row in an R dataframe (>10 000 rows) based on date range definitions in a separate, much smaller R dataframe (62 rows)?

My large dataframe, ConcFlow, looks similar to this when called via head(ConcFlow) :

```
    STATION Sampling.Year   DATE    Flow
1   2016-2017   13/03/2017  177.45
1   2016-2017   12/01/2017  96.798
1   2016-2017   11/01/2017  99.902
2   2016-2017   4/03/2017   109.74
2   2016-2017   5/03/2017   100.55
3   2016-2017   19/05/2017  2302.5
1   2017-2018   13/03/2018  177.45
1   2017-2018   12/01/2018  96.798
1   2017-2018   11/01/2018  99.902
2   2017-2018   4/03/2018   109.74
2   2017-2018   5/03/2018   100.55
3   2017-2018   19/05/2018  2302.5
```

The smaller dataset, First.Flush, contains dates for the start and end of the Australian wet season, like this:

```
  STATION   Sampling.Year   Start   End Season
1   2011-2012   1/01/2012   1/07/2012   Wet Season
1   2013-2014   1/01/2014   2/07/2014   Wet Season
1   2014-2015   1/01/2015   2/07/2015   Wet Season
1   2015-2016   23/12/2015  22/06/2016  Wet Season
1   2016-2017   12/12/2016  12/06/2017  Wet Season
2   2011-2012   18/10/2011  17/04/2012  Wet Season
2   2012-2013   24/12/2012  24/06/2013  Wet Season
2   2013-2014   1/01/2014   2/07/2014   Wet Season
2   2014-2015   1/01/2015   2/07/2015   Wet Season
2   2015-2016   23/12/2015  22/06/2016  Wet Season
3   2011-2012   18/10/2011  17/04/2012  Wet Season
```

I need to add a 'season' column to my ConcFlow dataframe where the value would be determined based on whether the ConcFlow$DATE falls in the ranges defined in First.Flush. If the DATE is within First.Flush$Start and First.Flush$End (inclusive) it needs to be defined as Wet Season. If not, it should be defined as Dry Season.

It also needs to repeat for each ConcFLow$STATION and ConcFLow$Sampling.Year

The best I've been able to produce is a for loop, but I don't know how to make it repeat for each STATION and Sampling.Year. I'm a novice in R and loops don't make too much sense to me yet. I don't know if this is the best approach - any help would be much appreciated thank you!

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(First.Flush$STATION))) {
  ConcFlow$Season <- ifelse(is.na(ConcFlow$Season) &
                              ConcFlow$DATE >= First.Flush$Start[i] &
                              ConcFlow$DATE < First.Flush$End[i],
                            First.Flush$Season[i], ConcFlow$Season)                       
}
```

This is a similar question but I don't know how to apply it to multiple factor levels within my df (ConcFlow$Station and ConFlow$Sampling.Year).
[categorize based on date ranges in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480624/categorize-based-on-date-ranges-in-r/65699646#65699646)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join` to join data based on range.

```
library(dplyr)

ConcFlow <- ConcFlow %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y'))
First.Flush <- First.Flush %>% mutate(across(c(Start, End), as.Date, '%d/%m/%Y'))

ConcFlow %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(First.Flush, 
          by = c('STATION', 'Sampling.Year', 'DATE' = 'Start', 'DATE' = 'End'), 
          match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  mutate(Season = replace(Season, is.na(Season), 'Dry Season')) -> result

result
```

First convert the date columns to date class in both the datasets, find out the rows where `STATION` and `Sampling.Year` matches exactly and `DATE` is in between `Start` and `End`, those rows automatically get `Season` value from `First.Flush`. The rows which are out of range get `NA` which can be replaced with 'Dry Season'.

You might need to clean up some column names in `result` at the end.